# Using JQUERY to add a <p> element but nothing happens

Tags: jquery

I have a simple JQUERY script that I have in the document head.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
     $(".quick-book-pc").prepend("<p>prepended paragraph</p>")
});
```

It supposed to locate the first DIV with the class .quick-book-pc and add the paragraph and inner text, When the window loads there are no errors but the paragraph is not added.

If I run the script in the console it adds the paragraph fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: try with document load

Comment: Should work fine (other than that it will not be limited to the first `.quick-book-pc`, but add a paragraph to all of them.) Why `$(window).on('load'` though, and not the usual https://api.jquery.com/ready/ ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide an [mcve] (I. E. With HTML and using the live demo feature of the question editor).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for your reference:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".quick-book-pc").prepend("<p>prepended paragraph</p>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quick-book-pc">
  quick-book-pc
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your DIV.quick-book-pc is added after the page load. Use MutationObserver to detect that:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

const callback = mutationList => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    const parent = $(mutation.addedNodes).filter(".quick-book-pc");
    if(parent.length){
      parent.prepend("<p>prepended paragraph</p>");
      observer.disconnect();
      observer = null;
      return;
    }
  }
};  

let observer;
const div = $(".quick-book-pc");
if(!div.length){
  observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
  observer.observe(document.body,  { childList: true, subtree: true });
} else {
  $(".quick-book-pc").prepend("<p>prepended paragraph</p>");
}

setTimeout(() => $('body').append('<div class="quick-book-pc">quick-book-pc</div>'));

</script>
```